# Image not updating in render when pixels changed using bpy

Tags: materials

I've got the following simple setup:

```
import os
import pathlib
import bpy
import numpy as np

for i in range(10):
    if i == 0:
        # Add a camera
        cam = bpy.data.cameras.new("Camera")
        cam_ob = bpy.data.objects.new("Camera", cam)
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(cam_ob)
        bpy.context.scene.camera = cam_ob
        cam_ob.location = [0, 0, 15]

        # Add a light
        light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="SUN", type="SUN")
        light_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name="SUN", object_data=light_data)
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_obj)

        # Create plane
        vertices = [
            (-5, -5, 0), (5, -5, 0), (5, 5, 0), (-5, 5, 0)
        ]
        m = bpy.data.meshes.new("Cube Mesh")
        m.from_pydata(vertices, [], [range(len(vertices))])
        o = bpy.data.objects.new("Cube", m)
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(o)

        # Add a material
        mat = bpy.data.materials.new("Plane")
        m.materials.append(mat)
        mat.use_nodes = True

        # Create an image texture
        tex = mat.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexImage")
        bsdf = [node for node in mat.node_tree.nodes if node.bl_idname ==
                "ShaderNodeBsdfPrincipled"]
        assert len(bsdf) == 1
        mat.node_tree.links.new(
            tex.outputs["Color"], bsdf[0].inputs["Base Color"])
        tex.image = bpy.data.images.new("Albedo", width=200, height=200)

    # Update image pixels
    color = [np.random.random(), np.random.random(), np.random.random(), 1]
    albedo = np.full((200, 200, 4), color, dtype=np.float32)
    tex.image.pixels.foreach_set(
        albedo.ravel().tolist(),
    )

    # Render
    outdir = pathlib.Path("output")
    os.makedirs(str(outdir), exist_ok=True)
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = "PNG"
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = str(outdir / f"render-{i}.png")
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=False, write_still=True)
```

I'm rendering 10 images of a plane with an image texture.
At every iteration I'm creating an image with a random color and modifying the shader texture pixels.

The weird thing is that all the rendered images are the same. They all have the color applied on the first iteration.

[image]

Once the script has finished, if I go to the shading tab, I see that the image texture applied to the BSDF Base Color is different to the one being rendered. Even if I render manually (F12) I still get the original blue color, despite the color being the pink one:

[image]

If I manually re-apply the material to the object and re-render, I get the pink color on the render.

Is there a way to update the texture node before rendering?

Comment: Hello ! It's a shot in the dark but maybe try https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Image.html#bpy.types.Image.update

Comment: May I ask why does the Python have this test ... if i == 0 ... ?

Comment: Through a single execution of the Python script how many times do you believe ... color = [np.random.random(), np.random.random(), np.random.random(), 1] is executed?  How many different colors being created is your goal?